# React-Native: Unable to add or set() document using firestore when app is Offline(no internet access)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I'm facing an issue while using .set() function in offline mode for creating a document in firestore. But .update() , .get() and .delete() functions are working in offline mode.

below is the code snippet

```
    firebase.firestore().collection(this.state.mainCollectionId)
      .doc(this.state.authKey)
      .collection(collectionId.toString())
      .doc(docId)
      .get()
      .then(docData => {

        if (docData.exists) {
          // console.log("daily Activity exists");

        } else {

         firebase.firestore().collection(this.state.mainCollectionId)
            .doc(this.state.authKey)
            .collection(collectionId.toString())
            .doc(docId)
            .set({
              id:1234,
              collectionId: collectionId.toString(),
              authKey: this.state.userDatails.authKey,
              name: this.state.userDatails.name,
              email: this.state.userDatails.email

      }).then(data =>{});

}
});
```

and error that I'm getting:

```
> Error: Firestore: The service is currently unavailable. (firestore/unavailable).
at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:146)
at NativeModules.js:95
at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:392)
at MessageQueue.js:128
at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:291)
at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:127)
at debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Answer (score 2):

I got to know the answer for this question. there is a if condition **If(docData.exists)** need to remove this code because firebase uses the cache in device. The if condition will look for the document that is not there in the cache.